# Who is the man in Slate’s Impeach-O-Meter?

Tags: donald-trump, impeachment

[image: Impeach-O-Meter by Slate]

This picture from [Slate’s article](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2019/09/trump-impeachment-chances-ukraine-call-release-edition.html) is a scale showing an estimated probability of Trump’s impeachment. It includes several Trump’s faces, from happy to unhappy.

The man in the end of the scale (100% chance of impeachment), however, wears glasses and does not look like Trump. Who is he and how is he related to presidential impeachment?

Comment: It's Mitch McConnell, the current Senate Majority leader. I assume Slate picked him with a dour look on his face at guaranteed impeachment because he's used the Trump presidency very effectively towards his political gains, but I have no reason to assume he'd wouldn't be just as if not more so effective with a president Pence. Regardless of how you feel about the man's policies, there is no denying the fact that he is an _extremely_ good politician.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's Senate Majority Leader Mitch McConnell.

[image]

If Trump is impeached, then the trial will occur in the Senate where Senator McConnell, as the leader of the GOP there, will have the power to shape the impeachment trial and, likely, determine whether the GOP controlled Senate will vote to convict or acquit him.

Comment: Indeed, McConnell may refuse to take up the trial at all, given his history of ignoring norms. There is no clear requirement in the constitution that the Senate take up the matter after the House impeaches a president. Only that the Senate has the sole power to try, as the House has the sole power to impeach.